# How to update specific column in a GridView using Ajax ModalPopUpExtender control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am developing a web-based suggestions box program for my company where the employees can submit any safety suggestions they have. Now, I am working on the Administration part of this system.

The Admin will be able to see all suggestions listed in a GridView control. In the last column of the GridView, the status will be listed there. When the Admin clicks on the status of one of these suggestion, a new pop-up window (asp.net ajax ModalPopUpExtender) will be appeared with listing all the possible status such as: actioned, approved... etc. And when the Admin selects one of these status, the status of the suggestion will be updated in the database. ***I wrote the code but still it doesn't update the status of the suggestion,***

**so could you please help me in modifying it?**

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name...
SafetySuggestionsLog: ID, Title, Description, Username, StatusID
SafetySuggestionsStatus: ID, Status
```

**ASP.NET code:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="900px" CssClass="mGrid" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" CssClass="alt" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "True" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="DivisionShortcut" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />

                <%-- This to make status be opened and edited through the Ajax ModalPopUp Window --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSuggestionStatus" Text='<%#Eval("Status")%>'
                                        OnClick="lnkSuggestionStatus_Click">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />--%>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnModalPopUp" style="display:none" />

        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender ID="modalPopUpExtender1"
                                        runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp" 
                                        PopupControlID="pnlPopUp" 
                                        BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle"
                                        PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle" 
                                        OkControlID="OKButton">
        </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPopUp">

                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="StatusList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                                            RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left" DataSourceID="SuggestionStatusDataSource"
                                            DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID">
                        <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="ACTIONED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="APPROVED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" Value="PENDING" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option4" runat="server" Value="TRANSFERRED" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SuggestionStatusDataSource" runat="server"
                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <asp:Button ID="confirmButton" runat="server" Text="Confirm" 
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to send an email notification about the safety suggestion to the owner?')" 
                                OnClick="btnSendStatus_Click" />

            <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void lnkSuggestionStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkSuggestionStatus = sender as LinkButton;

//var safetySuggestionsId=

        //get reference to the row selected 
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)lnkSuggestionStatus.NamingContainer;


        //set the selected index to the selected row so that the selected row will be highlighted
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = gvrow.RowIndex;

        //show the modalPopUp
        modalPopUpExtender1.Show();
    }

public void btnSendStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var statusID = StatusList.SelectedValue;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //For updating the status of the safety suggestion
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsStatus SET ID= @statusID where ID=@SafetySuggestionsID"";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", statusID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        SendSuggestionStatusToUser(statusID);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

**When I debugged the code, I got the following error:**

```
SqlException was unhandled by user code 
 Must declare the scalar variable "@SafetySuggestionsID"
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I modified my code as you suggested:

```
protected void lnkSuggestionStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkSuggestionStatus = sender as LinkButton;

        //var safetySuggestionsId = 

        //get reference to the row selected 
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)lnkSuggestionStatus.NamingContainer;

        //set the selected index to the selected row so that the selected row will be highlighted
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = gvrow.RowIndex;

        HiddenField1.Value = gvrow.RowIndex.ToString();

        //show the modalPopUp
        modalPopUpExtender1.Show();
    }

    public void btnSendStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var statusID = StatusList.SelectedValue;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //For updating the status of the safety suggestion
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog SET StatusID= @statusID where ID=@SafetySuggestionsID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(statusID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SafetySuggestionsID", Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //reset the value of hiddenfield
            HiddenField1.Value = "-1";
        }

        //SendSuggestionStatusToUser(statusID);
    }
```

However, while I am debugging the code, I got the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable"@statusID"

I don't know why I am getting this error while I am already defined it.

**UPDATE 3:**

I added `GridView1.DataBind()` to update the GridView with the updated status of the selected suggestion but it does not work with me.

```
public void btnSendStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var statusID = StatusList.SelectedValue;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //For updating the status of the safety suggestion
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog SET StatusID= @statusID where ID=@SafetySuggestionsID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID", Convert.ToInt32(statusID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SafetySuggestionsID", Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //reset the value of hiddenfield
            HiddenField1.Value = "-1";
        }

        GridView1.DataBind();

        //SendSuggestionStatusToUser(statusID);
    }
```

**UPDATE 4:**
I added the following but it did not work:

```
public void btnSendStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var statusID = StatusList.SelectedValue;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //For updating the status of the safety suggestion
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog SET StatusID= @statusID where ID=@SafetySuggestionsID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID", Convert.ToInt32(statusID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SafetySuggestionsID", Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //reset the value of hiddenfield
            HiddenField1.Value = "-1";
        }

        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        GridView1.DataBind();


        //SendSuggestionStatusToUser(statusID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see `SafetySuggestionsID` defined anywhere...u have defined it as `statusID`

also when you are adding parameters, you are referring `ID`...please make these corrections or update the code in your query.

```
string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsStatus SET ID= @statusID";  // where??
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))  
        {  
            conn.Open();  
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))  
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))  
            {  

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID", statusID);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            }  
        }
```

**Update**:

```
"UPDATE SafetySuggestionsStatus SET ID= @statusID where ID=@SafetySuggestionsID"";
```

you have defined 2 parameters, but you are adding just 1 in your parameter colleciton:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", statusID); // id should be statusID
// also add @SafetySuggestionsID
```

**Update 2:**
in your `lnkSuggestionStatus_Click` event handler, get the value of the first column (ID) and store it in a class variable say safetySuggestionsId.

Then in your `btnSendStatus_Click` event handler, you can simply add:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))   
        {   
            conn.Open();   
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))   
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))   
            {   

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID ", statusID); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SafetySuggestionsID", safetySuggestionsId);   
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
            }   
        }
```

**Update 3:**
Hope the following works as this is untested...:

1. add a hidden field in your modal popup panel -->
2. then in your `lnkSuggestionStatus_Click` event handler, add:

   hiddenRowIndex.Value = row.Cells[1].Text; // trim if necessary
3. then when you save, in your `btnSendStatus_Click` event handler, you can simply add:

   ```
          ...
          ...   
           {   

               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID ", statusID); 
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SafetySuggestionsID", 
                                           Convert.ToInt32(hiddenRowIndex.Value));   
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
           } 
           // reset hiddenRowIndex
           hiddenRowIndex.Value = "-1";
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I modified the code, but still I did not get what I want. Could you please help me with it? I think I am confused a little bit.

Comment: can u update on what is happening now? it will be better if you update the question so that new people viewing it can help

Comment: I know that but I don't know how to define it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Many thanks. Actually, I know this step and my problem is with getting the ID. How? Could you please have a look at my updated code and help me in getting the ID.

Comment: I modified my code according to your suggestion, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: change this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(statusID)); to
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID", Convert.ToInt32(statusID));

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works now, however, the selected value in ModalPopUp windows is not reflected and showed in the GridView. However, you saved my time man. Thanks.

Comment: for that you will have to rebind the grid.

Comment: I added it but it did not work. Look at my updated code above.

Comment: thank you very much for your continuous support. I already did what you suggested but it did work with me and I don't know why. Also, I tried to find an explanation to it but I could not find anything related to it.

Comment: Finally I got be able to fix it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this sample projects

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17722/GridView-with-a-single-ModalPopupExtender-Panel-fo

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/modalpopupextender_example_for.html

http://thinkofdotnet.blogspot.com/2012/05/edit-update-gridview-with-ajax.html

Comment: Hi dude, before my question here, I searched on the web and I couldn't be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I know how to fix it. my problem was with the HiddenField which I was assigning it to the index of the selected row immediately without specifying to be assigned to the DataKey of that row.

I was just needing to modify this in the lnkSuggestionStatus_Click method:

```
HiddenField1.Value = GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```